# PHP Find median value from array and return key and value?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of channels, so far I know how to return min and max values like this:

```
// clear from any empty channels
$channels = array_filter($scan['channels']);

// get min/max values
$min = array_keys($channels, min($channels));
$max = array_keys($channels, max($channels));
// this returns the channel name which is what I need
```

So far I would like to get the median key (channel) name, how can I achieve this?

```
// this is the array of channels
Array
(
    [chann_1] => 155.755
    [chann_2] => 154.61
    [chann_3] => 156.719
    [chann_4] => 156.727
    [chann_5] => 155.797
    [chann_6] => 157.615
    [chann_7] => 154.257
    [chann_8] => 151.724
    [chann_9] => 156.549
    [chann_10] => 156.594
    [chann_11] => 157.56
    [chann_12] => 156.405
)
```

Comment: you want the average of all the values rite? and if yes than do array_sum($channels)/count($channels)

Comment: god, average is the same as median, lol, let me try that

Comment: but I do not need the value but the key (channel) name, any ideas?

Comment: Average may not have a key associated to it. `$arr[1,10]` average is 5 but there is no key for 5

Comment: "Mean" means "average".  "Median" means the middle value.  If you have an even number of elements, you will not be able to access the "median" key because the median value does not have a key.  It is the space between two elements.  Relevant page: [Calculating Median of an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52434519/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:.

Sort the array.
Get the array keys.
Then half of count of array_keys is the median value. (I added round just in case).

```
$arr = Array(
"chann_1" => 155.755,
"chann_2" => 154.61,
"chann_3" => 156.719,
"chann_4" => 156.727,
"chann_5" => 155.797,
"chann_6" => 157.615,
"chann_7" => 154.257,
"chann_8" => 151.724,
"chann_9" => 156.549,
"chann_10" => 156.594,
"chann_11" => 157.56,
"chann_12" => 156.405);

Arsort($arr);
//Var_dump($arr);
$keys = array_keys($arr);
Echo $keys[round(count($keys)/2)];
```

https://3v4l.org/ER3d4

Comment: round() does not work if the array has one element. Use floor() instead

Comment: @PaulH if the array only have one element you don't need to find the median value. Just do a `if(count($arr) >1)` and else just output the only element in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Use`array_search()`.`$max_key=array_search($max,$yourArray);$min_key=array_search($min,$yourArray);$median=$max_key+$min_key/2;`of course it depends on your Array size.

Try `$median=array_search($max+$min/2,$yourArra);`

Comment: I need the media key not value

Comment: array_search() returns the key of a value .

Comment: You are not calculating median, you are calculating average. The average may or may not have a item in the array, the median however has a value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

`array_slice()` is a direct tool to return the key-value pair after dividing the array count in half to find the position of the targeted element.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/CNbF0))

```
asort($array);
var_export(
    array_slice($array, intdiv(count($array), 2), 1, true)
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'chann_9' => 156.549,
)
```

As mentioned in my comment under the question, when there is an even number of elements in the array, the true median value will be the average of the middle two values.  Because you can't have "half of a key", my script floors the calculation to the earlier of the two middle elements; if you want the later occurring element (of the middle two), you can use `arsort()` or round the calculation up to the next integer (instead of rounding down as is done in my snippet).