# Variable length data

Tags: php

Im not sure how to approach this. I have varying amounts in multiple arrays. Im trying to get a score/rank based on which is higher and which is lower. However the number of items in the array will affect it.

So basically a value of 10 is high score and a value of 0 is low score.

```
$data1 = "4.12,9.95,2.44,3.80,10.68,-1.15,11.81";//possibly get median value from number set?
$data2 = "12.61"; // high score 
$data3 = "4.55,9.70,6.44,-1.04,12.55"; // 

$arr1 = explode(',',$data1);

foreach ($arr1 as $a1){

///calculate here




}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Calculate the rank how?

Comment: Ive updated the question. Basically trying to get a rank from low to high, 0 being low and 10 being high. The issue is how to get an average number from $data1 and $data3, i was thinking of doing a median value of the set to get a rank but not sure if this the correct apporoach

Comment: So what do you wanna do? To get a median, sort the array and get the element from the middle.

Comment: yes. i think that will work. i just dont know how to get a median value from multiple numbers

Comment: Try this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434519/calculating-median-of-an-array-in-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating Median of an array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52434519/calculating-median-of-an-array-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the following code that will calculate mean, median and mode.

This takes in strings of scores (that are already delimeted by commas), then merges them together into an array.

```
<?php

$data1 = "4.12,9.95,2.44,3.80,10.68,-1.15,11.81";//possibly get median value from number set?
$data2 = "12.61"; // high score 
$data3 = "4.55,9.70,6.44,-1.04,12.55"; // 

$merged = implode(',', [$data1, $data2, $data3]);

$scores = explode(',', $merged);

function mean($arr) 
{
    $count = count($arr);
    $sum = array_sum($arr);
    return number_format(($sum / $count), 2);
}

function median($numbers) 
{
    sort($numbers);
    $middleLength = floor((count($numbers) - 1) / 2);
    return number_format(($numbers[$middleLength] + $numbers[$middleLength + 1]) / 2, 2);
}

function mode($numbers)
{
    sort($numbers);
    $countRepeatedValues = array_count_values($numbers);
    $maxValue = max($countRepeatedValues);
    foreach ($countRepeatedValues as $number => $repeatedValue) {
        if ($repeatedValue == $maxValue) {
            return $number;
        }
    }
}

echo 'Mean: ' . mean($scores) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Median: ' . median($scores) . PHP_EOL;
echo 'Mode: ' . mode($scores) . PHP_EOL;
```